# How to use wild card with IN operator

Tags: sql

In a SQL query I have

`SELECT TRIM FROM CARS WHERE MODEL IN (:param1)`

In some cases certain trims are required to be returned, based on `:param1` value, in other cases all trims are required to be returned.

How can I pass a wild card to `:param1`?

Similar to this example: https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/in.php

Comment: I don't think you can pass anything that will act as wildcard for :param1, but what is the motivation for this? I'm confused about how you can detect the scenario where you want to pass the wildcard, but can't change the query in that circumstance.

Comment: No reason to be confused as you cannot pass wildcards. You can write the necessary code to process your parameter to infer wildcards but you actually only pass a string.

Comment: When you say *"In a PL/SQL query"* do you really mean you have a SQL statement embedded in a stored procedure or function? If so, you should include the PL/SQL program which executes this query. It is **extremely pertinent** to providing a solution.

Comment: Hmmm, well the `[plsql]` tag is the only tag you provided but it seems that your tech stack contains no actual PL/SQL just regular SQL.

Comment: @ABC I have updated the tags

Answer (score 1):

You cannot pass a wild card to IN operator in SQL